# TabbarController not hiding when opening CameraController (BarCodeScanner)

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, barcode-scanner

I have a BarCodeScanner-viewController which I call from 3 different views. My app also has a tabbarController. Problem is, the tabbar hides from two of the viewControllers, while the third one always shows the tabbarController, while in cameraMode (barCodeScanner).

I've tried to set the ´self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true´ in both viewDidLoad(), viewDidAppear() and viewWillAppear() and changed it to false on viewWillDisappear()

I have also tested to set 'scanner.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true' without result.

```
// working:
setUpBackButton(withTitle: NSLocalizedString("button_cancel", comment: ""))
        let scanner = BarCodeScanner()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scanner, animated: true)
        scanner.callback = { result in
            // code with result
        }


// working: 
setUpBackButton()
        let scanner = BarCodeScanner()
        scanner.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scanner, animated: true)
        scanner.callback = { result in
            // code with result
        }


// NOT WORKING (i.e. not hiding the tabbarController):
let scanner = BarCodeScanner()
        setupBackButton()
        scanner.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scanner, animated: true)
        scanner.callback = { result in
            // code with result
        }
```

I wan't the tabbar to be hidden in the third example too.

Comment: instead of pushing, present  scannerController

Comment: @AbuUlHassan yeah that works, nice, thanks. Any idea why the first two work with push?

Comment: in third you are using 
let scanner = BarCodeScanner()
        setupBackButton()
        scanner.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scanner, animated: true)
        scanner.callback = { result in
            // code with result
        }
here you are calling  setupBackButton() this functiona contains same code so may be duplicate code causing the issue

Comment: try by removeing 
setupBackButton() from third example and i think it will do the trick.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Sorry but that doesn't work. I will have to go with the present-option for now, which is fine for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: happy coding  :)

Comment: @AbuUlHassan If you add this as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: If you say, indeed it will help others to find answer quickly. batter idea thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Push actually adds a new controller in navigationController thats why your tabbar is not hiding to hide it with new controllers overlay you need to change push with present function in Thrid example

Replace

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scanner, animated: true)
```

With

```
self.navigationController?.present(scanner, animated: true, completion: nil)
```